# How to refresh the parent page and closing the child window using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

How to refresh the parent page and closing the child window using javascript  when I click the button in parent page asp.net 
I am able to refresh the parent page but my child window is not closing.
My C# Code is

```
 string script = @"<script>
        function RefreshParent()
        {
          window.close();
           window.opener.location.reload();
          }RefreshParent();
</script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ssr", script);
```

Comment: try to call reload() method before window.close();

Answer (score 1):

just try this code in your child window

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(this.GetType(),
                                       "close",
       "<script language=javascript>window.opener.location.reload(true);
                      self.close();</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

**window.parent.location.reload();**

Answer (score 0):

Example with a link:

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!-- Start
document.write('<a href="javascript:self.close()" onClick="opener.location.reload(true);">Close</a>');
// Stop -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your child window before your parent window gets refreshed. Try it this way

```
<string script = @"<script>
            function RefreshParent()
            {
              window.opener.location.reload();
              window.close();              
              }RefreshParent();
    </script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ssr", script);
```